# What is alt+s doing to emacs in remmina/vnc?

Tags: keyboard, emacs, vnc, remmina

I am connecting to a centos system at work using vnc. The work server runs vncserver and I run remmina on my two local Ubuntu laptops (12.04 and 14.04). On either laptop, I can connect to the vnc server without problems. I am using emacs so usually when I want to search for something I type alt+s and it promps me for a string with which to search. However, if I hold down alt+s instead what happens is

> 1) The blinking cursor jumps to the other window.
>
> 2) Often, but not always the left mouse button does not work in emacs. Instead of clicking on things, a hand icon appears that does nothing.
>
> 3) Often, but not always. Keyboard keys don't do what I expect them to do. A keyboard shortcut that used to move the curser (eg ctrl+a) for instance now transposes test. Typing into emacs doesn't work.
>
> 4) Sometimes, but not always, I loose all control of the vnc window. If I type alt+s enough times I can increase the likelyhood of this symptom.
>
> 5) If I disconnect and reconnect from the vnc, everything goes back to normal

I can't duplicate this strange behavior outside of emacs. I also don't get this behaviour when I connect to emacs with ssh and -X.

Also, I looked in the preferences>keyboard section of remmina and there is no keyboard shortcut there pertaining to alt+s. s by itself used to toggle scaled mode, but I changed that to something else just in case. There was no improvement.

Any suggestions for how I can get alt+s to work as expected. Alternatively I'd settle for an explanation of why alt+s does what it does.

edit:
Please not that, in contrast to what is described in this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2280273
This effect happens when "Grab all keyboard events" is toggled on.

Furthemore, this effect also happens when I use "Remote Desktop Viewer" rather than Remmina.

I can get the same effect if I type [esc] and then s.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that alt+s isn't the keybinding for search at all. I was thinking of ctrl+s, which is the usual isearch-forward command. Somehow, I was typing ctrl+s when working with x windows and alt+s when in remmina and thinking everything worked in one case but not the other.